# Linear Feedback Shift Register Taps

Tags: random-number-generator, lfsr, shift-register

Linear feedback shift register tap charts are availale for registers of length 3 to 168. Does anyone have a chart for register lengths from 168 to 256 or beyond?

Answer (score 6):

When I need something on that tune I might use [Jörg's useful and ugly page of mathematical data](https://www.jjj.de/mathdata/).

In particular, [all-trinomial-primpoly](https://www.jjj.de/mathdata/all-trinomial-primpoly.txt) gives primitive GF(2) trinomials (LFSR with 2 taps, the minimum number) to degree 400. `100,63,0` tells you that $x^{100}+x^{63}+1$ is primitive, meaning the same as `100|100,63` at [LFSR Feedback Taps to 168 bits](https://web.archive.org/web/20140627102757/http://home1.gte.net:80/res0658s/electronics/LFSRtaps.html).

Also of interest is [eq-primpoly-w5](https://www.jjj.de/mathdata/eq-primpoly-w5.txt), giving one primitive pentanomial (LFSR with 4 taps) per degree up to 660. The entry `660 498 329 164 0` tells that $x^{660}+x^{498}+x^{329}+x^{164}+1$ is primitive (equivalent to `660|660,498,329,164` in a Feedback Taps table). Reference is given to: Janusz Rajski et Jerzy Tyszer, [Primitive Polynomials Over GF(2) of Degree up to 660 with Uniformly Distributed Coefficients](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1027422805851), which free main table [there](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Primitive-Polynomials-Over-GF(2)-of-Degree-up-to-Rajski-Tyszer/0b6b11bf32f4619acd8864f8a7fa8de4e931bcc8#extracted) (part [1](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Primitive-Polynomials-Over-GF(2)-of-Degree-up-to-Rajski-Tyszer/0b6b11bf32f4619acd8864f8a7fa8de4e931bcc8/figure/1), [2](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Primitive-Polynomials-Over-GF(2)-of-Degree-up-to-Rajski-Tyszer/0b6b11bf32f4619acd8864f8a7fa8de4e931bcc8/figure/2) [3](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Primitive-Polynomials-Over-GF(2)-of-Degree-up-to-Rajski-Tyszer/0b6b11bf32f4619acd8864f8a7fa8de4e931bcc8/figure/3)).

Further, [highbit-normalprimpoly](https://www.jjj.de/mathdata/highbit-normalprimpoly.txt) gives one primitive polynomial per degree up to 400, selected has having the lowest non-constant term as high as possible. That one is handy for software implementations, for the representation of the polynomials can be compressed into a small bitmask.